# Unable to compile with Error C2440 due to type cast from C to C++

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, casting

```
inline BOOL FupVmCall(ULONG_PTR hypercall_number, void *context) {
#pragma section(".asm", read, execute)
  __declspec(allocate(".asm")) static const BYTE CODE[] = {
      0x0F, 0x01, 0xC1, //    vmcall
      0x74, 0x0E,       //    jz      short errorWithCode
      0x72, 0x04,       //    jb      short errorWithoutCode
      0x48, 0x33, 0xC0, //    xor     rax, rax
      0xC3,             //    retn
                        // errorWithoutCode:
      0x48, 0xC7, 0xC0, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, //    mov     rax, 2
      0xC3,                                     //    retn
                                                // errorWithCode:
      0x48, 0xC7, 0xC0, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, //    mov     rax, 1
      0xC3,                                     //    retn
  };

  typedef unsigned char(__stdcall * AsmVmxCallType)(
      _In_ ULONG_PTR hypercall_number, _In_opt_ void *context);

#pragma warning(suppress : 4055)
  AsmVmxCallType AsmVmxCall = (AsmVmxCallType)CODE;

  __try {
    return AsmVmxCall(hypercall_number, context) == 0;
  } __except (EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER) {
    SetLastError(GetExceptionCode());
    return FALSE;
  }
}
```

I am trying to compile above code from C++ project with VS2019

If I change main file to main.c, it compiles without any problem

However, If I change it to main.cpp, I get C2440 type cast problem.

```
C2440   'type cast': cannot convert from 'const BYTE [27]' to 'AsmVmxCallType'
```

```
AsmVmxCallType AsmVmxCall = (AsmVmxCallType)CODE;
```

I even tried to wrap with `extern "C"` but did not solve the issue.

How can I make this typecast?

Comment: `reinterpret_cast<AsmVmxCallType>(CODE)` should work, assuming AsmVmxCallType is a pointer type. Of course this breaks C compatibility.

Answer (score 2):

You can first cast `CODE` to a void pointer, then cast that to your function pointer:

```
AsmVmxCallType AsmVmxCall = (AsmVmxCallType)(void *)CODE;
```